# Typed.js random word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, typed.js

Is there a way to get a random word with [Typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)?

```
$(function(){
  $(".element").typed({
    strings: ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor"],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
```

Output should be one of these words. (Lorem / Ipsum / Dolor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Math.Random()` to select a random item in the array

like:

```
$(function(){
    var stringArray = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor"];
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (stringArray.length - 1)); //random number between 0 and stringArray length
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: [stringArray[randomNumber]],
        typeSpeed: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I'm having a problem with the output, it show a random word from these 3, and that's ok, but it write letter by letter.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38gux0sj/2/

Comment: @Keyon whoops forgot to cast it in an array, check my edit

Comment: @Keyon the reason behind this is that the Typed library received a string "Lorem" while it expected an array like ["Lorem"], because of this it basically turned the string "Lorem" into an array like: ["L","o","r","e","m"]. I hope this explanation helped you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The feature is already built-in. Just add, `shuffle: true,`